# How to SQL INSERT CROSS JOIN with other parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to insert data into a table.  This query must select certain id's from two separate tables as well as a passed in parameter.  I was able to get the data from the two separate tables by using CROSS JOIN.  However, I'm not sure how to pass in a string as my third parameter.  Here is my statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (T2_ID, T3_ID)
SELECT T2_ID, T3_ID
FROM (SELECT T2_ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.NAME = 'BOB') AS T1
CROSS JOIN(SELECT T3_ID FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE3.DATA = 'BLARGH') AS T2;
```

I get the ID's I need back from the cross join but I also need to pass in one more parameter that is a string value.  How do I pass this in as well?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add a string in the select:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (T2_ID, T3_ID, <col>)
SELECT T2_ID, T3_ID, 'a string' 
FROM (SELECT T2_ID FROM TABLE2 
      WHERE TABLE2.NAME = 'BOB') AS T1
CROSS JOIN(SELECT T3_ID 
           FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE3.DATA = 'BLARGH') AS T2;
```

Strictly speaking you don't need the sub-selects:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (T2_ID, T3_ID, <col>)
SELECT T2_ID, T3_ID, 'a string' 
FROM TABLE2 AS T1 
CROSS JOIN TABLE3 AS T2
WHERE T1.NAME = 'BOB'
  AND T2.DATA = 'BLARGH'
```

Comment: you can add a string to the select and it won't be a problem?  My string will be a variable.  I figured the select would break.

Comment: That should be fine, note that you have to add the name of the column in the insert clause. If possible use prepared statements and parameter markers.

Comment: If you use prepared statement you may have to cast the parameter marker like: `INSERT INTO TABLE1 (T2_ID, T3_ID, <col>) SELECT T2_ID, T3_ID, cast(? as ...) FROM ... WHERE T1.NAME = ? AND ...`